# Notify users that the change was ok after saga, react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, saga

I want to notify the user that the change he did was successful, and to confirm what he changed. E.g. if the users hit a button called "activate".

I have a saga that fires a PUT to change the object in the database, then I fire a GET to fetch the new list of objects, where the updated object are in it. I want to have a notification message showing that object x changed state from inactive to active, and then I want the notification to go away.

Comment: May you elaborate a bit what you have already done? I mean, do you have some code?